# Server-loaded buildings function for an iOS game

Tags: game, objective-c, ios, cocoa

I'm working on a game for iOS devices and this is the function we use to create server-loaded buildings. The server loading is in another function and everything works just fine, but I was wondering if this function could be prettier? This function runs every 60 seconds as we reload the whole base (with the buildings in) frequently, maybe I should reuse the buildings if nothing has changed server-side?

There's another function that just clears all the subviews in the UIView "sandbox" to reset the base upon reload.

```
-(void)loadBuilding:(BuildingButton *)building 
{    
    //building.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    if(building.buildUpgrading > 0 && building.buildLevel == 1)  //Building is being built
    {
        HJManagedImageV *constructionImage = [[HJManagedImageV alloc] init];
        constructionImage.url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mysite.com/img/base/construction/%@",building.buildConstrImg]];
        constructionImage.greyscale = greyscale;
        constructionImage.resize = 1;
        constructionImage.reloadSuperview = 1;
        constructionImage.animateSetImage = YES;
        constructionImage.delegate = building;
        //[constructionImage showLoadingWheel];
        [appDelegate.objManager manage:constructionImage];
        constructionImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, constructionImage.image.size.width, constructionImage.image.size.height);

        [building addSubview:constructionImage];
        [building bringSubviewToFront:constructionImage];
        [building setNeedsDisplay];
        [constructionImage release];
    } else { //Building is normal!
        //---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        //ANIMATED IMAGES IMPLEMENTS HERE -------------------------------------------------------------------------
        if([building.buildImage isEqualToString:@"oil_refinery_desert.gif"])  //Images that need animating, use ID instead?
        {
            UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"oil_refinery_desert01.png"];
            UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"oil_refinery_desert02.png"];
            UIImage *image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"oil_refinery_desert03.png"];
            UIImage *image4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"oil_refinery_desert04.png"];
            UIImage *image5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"oil_refinery_desert05.png"];
            //Make GREY!
            if (greyscale) {
                image1 = [self convertImageToGrayScale:image1];
                image2 = [self convertImageToGrayScale:image2];
                image3 = [self convertImageToGrayScale:image3];
                image4 = [self convertImageToGrayScale:image4];
                image5 = [self convertImageToGrayScale:image5];
            }
            NSArray *images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, nil];
            UIImageView *animationSequence = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, image1.size.width, image1.size.height)];
            animationSequence.animationImages = images;
            [images release];
            [building addSubview:animationSequence];
            [building bringSubviewToFront:animationSequence];
            [building setNeedsDisplay];
            //[building setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
            [building setFrame:CGRectMake(building.frame.origin.x, building.frame.origin.y, image1.size.width, image1.size.height)];
            animationSequence.animationDuration = 0.75;
            animationSequence.animationRepeatCount = 0;
            [animationSequence startAnimating];
            [animationSequence release];
        } else {
            //[building setImage:imageLoader.image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            HJManagedImageV *imageLoader = [[HJManagedImageV alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,0,0)];
            imageLoader.url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mysite.com/img/base/%@",building.buildImage]];
            imageLoader.greyscale = greyscale;
            imageLoader.resize = 1;
            imageLoader.reloadSuperview = 1;
            imageLoader.animateSetImage = YES;
            imageLoader.delegate = building;
            //[imageLoader showLoadingWheel];
            [appDelegate.objManager manage:imageLoader];
            [building addSubview:imageLoader];
            [imageLoader release];
            //[building setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        }

        //Is the building upgrading?
        if(building.buildUpgrading > 0) 
        {
            HJManagedImageV *constructionImage = [[HJManagedImageV alloc] init];
            constructionImage.url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.mysite.com/img/base/upgrade/%@",building.buildUpgradeImg]];
            constructionImage.greyscale = greyscale;
            constructionImage.resize = 1;
            constructionImage.reloadSuperview = 1;
            constructionImage.animateSetImage = YES;
            constructionImage.delegate = building;
            //[constructionImage showLoadingWheel];
            [appDelegate.objManager manage:constructionImage];
            constructionImage.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, building.frame.size.width, building.frame.size.height);

            [building addSubview:constructionImage];
            [building bringSubviewToFront:constructionImage];
            [building setNeedsDisplay];
            [constructionImage release];
        }
    }

    if(building.buildID == 999) { //Road is disabled!
        building.userInteractionEnabled = FALSE;
    }

    NSLog(@"Loaded: %@", building);
    if(greyscale == 0) {
        [building addTarget:self action:@selector(playButtonSound) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [building addTarget:self action:@selector(loadWindow:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    [sandbox addSubview:building];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should rewrite `convertImageToGrayScale:` to `grayScaled` in a category on UIImage

```
 image1 = [self grayScaled];
```

in the following block you should add the images to array first, and then loop through it, to perform `for(UIImage *image in images){image = [image grayScaled];}`

```
 UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"oil_refinery_desert01.png"];
 UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"oil_refinery_desert02.png"];
 UIImage *image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"oil_refinery_desert03.png"];
 UIImage *image4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"oil_refinery_desert04.png"];
 UIImage *image5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"oil_refinery_desert05.png"];
        //Make GREY!
 if (greyscale) {
        image1 = [self convertImageToGrayScale:image1];
        image2 = [self convertImageToGrayScale:image2];
        image3 = [self convertImageToGrayScale:image3];
        image4 = [self convertImageToGrayScale:image4];
        image5 = [self convertImageToGrayScale:image5];
 }
 NSArray *images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, nil];
```

becomes:

```
 UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"oil_refinery_desert01.png"];
 UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"oil_refinery_desert02.png"];
 UIImage *image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"oil_refinery_desert03.png"];
 UIImage *image4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"oil_refinery_desert04.png"];
 UIImage *image5 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"oil_refinery_desert05.png"];

 NSArray *images = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, nil];

 if (greyscale) {
     for(UIImage *image in images){
         image= [image grayScaled];
     }
 }
```

can you confirm, that this is necessary:

```
 [building addSubview:animationSequence];
 [building bringSubviewToFront:animationSequence];
 [building setNeedsDisplay];
```

I think, `[building addSubview:animationSequence];` should be sufficient.

BTW: IMHO Class names for Views should end with the word View, i.e. Building becomes BuildingView. Same for Controllers.

`if(building.buildID == 999) { //Road is disabled!` looks a bit suspicious to me. Adding a meta information to an object shouldn't be necessary in a OO environment. I assume a RoadModel to be a subclass of an BuildingModel (or FacilityModel,…), so the better check would be `if([building isKindOfClass:[Road class]])`

Comment: please see my addition

Comment: and another edit